# starting oracle 10g on ubuntu, Listener failed to start

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, sqlplus

I have installed oracle 10g on a ubuntu 10.x, This is my first time installation. After installing I tried to start it with the command below.

```
tsegay@server-name:/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin$ lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 29-DEC-2010 22:46:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> start
Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/log/listener.log
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
TNS-12555: TNS:permission denied
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00525: Insufficient privilege for operation
   Linux Error: 1: Operation not permitted

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

my listener.ora file looks like this:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = acct-vmserver)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

I can guess the problem is with permission issue, But i dont know where I have to do the change on permission.

Any help is appreciated ...

EDIT##

When i run with the command sudo, i got this

```
tsegay@server-name:/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1$ sudo ./bin/lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 30-DEC-2010 01:01:03

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting ./bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

./bin/tnslsnr: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00517: Lost contact
   Linux Error: 32: Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 2):

The listener must be started using the same account you used to install Oracle. Typically, this account is named 'oracle'.

Using sudo, the command line should be:

```
sudo -H -u oracle /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/lsnrctl start
```

(btw, I don't think that using Ubuntu to run an Oracle database is supported by Oracle)

Comment: Not supported but working very well: http://www.pythian.com/news/13291/installing-oracle-11gr2-enterprise-edition-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/

Answer (score 1):

Is your LD_LIBRARY_PATH set  to include the Oracle library directories?

Did you run the root.sh script after you finished the installation?

Answer (score 1):

After a painful process of installing the **Oracle DB 11.2.0.1**, Linux x86-64,  on a **Lubuntu 11.10 x86_64**, involving many fixes of makefiles, a few remarks to make the listener work:

- always use the Oracle DB install owner, e.g.: **`su - oracle`**
- **`export ORACLE_HOME="/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1"`**
- **`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${ORACLE_HOME}/lib"`**
- **`export PATH="${ORACLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"`**
- **`dbstart`** to start up the DB, listener should start automatically
- **`lsnrctl status`** to verify it is really listening

It's better to permanently keep those 3 exports in **`oracle`**'s **`.bashrc`** file.

If the listener status is still not OK, ensure that the **`oracle`** user is a member of a network-allowed group, in case of Lubuntu it's the group **`netdev`**. You can set this in *System tools > Users and Groups > oracle > Advanced Settings > User Privileges > Connect to wireless and ethernet networks*. Or alternatively just issue **`sudo usermod -aG netdev oracle`** using an administrative account, in your case `tsegay`. Remember to start a new shell (or logout + login) for **`oracle`** user to see the changes.

P.S.: My **`listener.ora`** is like:

```
LISTENER =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS =
            (PROTOCOL = tcp)
            (HOST = localhost)
            (PORT = 1521)
        )
    )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
    (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
            (GLOBAL_DBNAME = PLSExtProc)
            (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
            (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Lubuntu 11.10 ? Dear friend you are not canonical at all :) For best results Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `sudo lsnrctl`, assuming you have sufficient rights.

Comment: Thanks, Please see above what i got when i run with sudo.

Comment: Well, perhaps an installation/configuration issue is similar to http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/68299/2/, http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/81352/2/